# module a code error trying to separate my code

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I tried to separate my code to a file called: `app2d.js` and it gave me a weird error [Error messege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa1ju.png)
The code in app.js:

```
const app2d = require("./app2d");
var a = 10
var b = 20
const total = app2d.sum(a,b);
console.log("The total of A and B is: ", total)
```

The code in app2d:

```
function sum(a,b){

    return a+b;
}
module.exports = {
    sum
};
```

Comment: @1556089774 I am not using a code in a browser though

Comment: can you explain the error message image? it looks like error from ie

Comment: Are you writing the .js files for client side (browser) rendering or are they server side (node.js) files

Comment: server side (node.js) file @Lundii

Comment: @1556089774 The error message is what you see what do you mean?

Comment: looks like this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540555/getting-microsoft-jscript-compilation-error

Comment: "If using any editor aside from a plain text editor (notepad++, notepad, sublime etc) ensure the file is in-fact set to output plain-text (bone-head move but often overlooked)" He said it and I can't understand it I do use notepad++ but I don't understand what he wants me to do

Comment: @1556089774 Problem is soulved the second commend which he didn't mark as good fixed it weird but ok haha thanks.

Comment: I tried to google the error `window script host` and it appears to be a very common error, I can't read the details now but I will suggest you check it out if you can find the solution over here.

Comment: @Lundii Read my last post, I solved it all I had to do is write node before I run it  which before I just did the name of the program